# Ubuntu 16.04 completely freezes when using Nvidia card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

If I change the PRIME profile configuration on Nvidia XServer Settings to NVIDIA performance mode, it tells me to logout and log in again to apply the alterations. When I do that, nothing changes. However, when I reboot, the changes finally take place, I am able to use the system for a couple of minutes and then Ubuntu freezes. Nothing works. I can't even switch to tty and the only thing I can do is to press the power button. When the system starts again, Intel is running and if I change to Nvidia, the process starts again (reboot, freezes, etc)

My graphics card is a GeForce 940m. If I run `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` the result is the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
```

Oddly, the result of `prime-select query` while using Intel is `unkown`. During the few minutes I am able to use the Nvidia card, the result of `prime-select query` is `nvidia`.

I don't believe there is any hardware issue with the graphics card, since it works fine on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am also having the same problem with my NVIDIA Geforce 940M. However mine is on my laptop.

```
mylaptop@laptop:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Pegatron Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
--
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Pegatron GM108M [Geforce 940M]    
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

When I run:

```
mylaptop@laptop:~$ prime-select query
nvidia
```

I am running ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Did you manage to fix your problem?